using peertube-cli to upload every video file in a folder with powershell
I have successfully installed peertube-cli on my windows PC, in powershell.
I have sucessfully created an auth instance to my peertube site.
I have successfully uploaded a test file manually with the cli command.
 peertube-cli upload --video-name 'test' --file 'e:\videos\test.mp4'

What I want to do now is upload 100 or so files in a folder, the filenames are handily named 001-,002- etc.
but I don't have a clue how to retrieve the filename, upload the video, go to the next file name.
I tried googling, because someone must have done this before
this link gives me an idea for retrieving filenames as a string
https://github.com/Chocobozzz/PeerTube/issues/4965
But my problem is I don't know how to write a powershell script to loop through all the names.
I tried to ask chatgpt and frankensteined together a script that I have not run.
    $folderpath = "E:\test\"
$videofiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderpath -Include *.mp4 -File
foreach ($video in $videofiles) {
$form = @{
"file" = Get-Item $video.Fullname
}
peertube-cli upload --video-name $video --file $folderpath\$video
}


I am not sure what is being accomplished by the $form = statement. It should be possible to use the video variable as-is.
$folderpath = "E:\test\"
$videofiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderpath -Include *.mp4 -File
foreach ($video in $videofiles) {
    peertube-cli upload --video-name $video.FullName --file $folderpath\$video.Name
}

